# to match the data from database this error is come

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This code give the error dbpassword variable cannot resolve

```
   loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get the user details email or password
            String useremail = emailornumber.getText().toString();
            String password = userpassword.getText().toString();

            //fetch the password from the database
            String storedPassword = databaseAdapter.getUserInfo(dbpassword);

            // check if password is match
            if(userpassword.equals(dbpassword)){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You are Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

DatabaseAdater

```
  public Cursor getUserInfo(String dbpassword)  
               {

             Cursor mCursor =
                     db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                     KEY_FULLNAME, KEY_EMAILID}, KEY_PASSWORD + "=" +  dbpassword , null,
                     null, null, null, null);
                     if (mCursor != null) {
                     mCursor.moveToNext();
                     }
                     return mCursor;
                     }
```

Comment: Where is the error ? Please post error log in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is located here:

`String storedPassword = databaseAdapter.getUserInfo(dbpassword);`

Your method `getUserInfo` returns a Cursor, not a String.